# Upload file to google calendar

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

How can I upload a file to a google calender event as an attachment?  With google labs you can enable file uploading in google calender, but how can I upload a file to a calender event in java?

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html

I noticed that they have an API which works for creating/editing calender events, but I didn't see anything in regards to file uploads.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [API developer's guide](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#CreatingEvents), you can set the content of your CalendarEventEntry through the setContent method:

> The entry content is represented by a
>   [Content](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/Content.html) object, a class that can hold
>   either plain text or other forms of
>   content, including XML and binary
>   data. (But the [setContent](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/BaseEntry.html#setContent%28com.google.gdata.data.TextConstruct%29) method can
>   also accept a `TextConstruct`).

Then, using the same example listed at the guide, and using the [`com.google.gdata.data.OtherContent`](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/OtherContent.html) class of the provided API:

```
byte[] binaryContent=//... your binary content to attach
OtherContent yourContent=new OtherContent();
yourContent.setBytes(binaryContent);
//don't know if this is mandatory... yourContent.setMimeType(ContentType.ANY);


CalendarEventEntry myEntry = new CalendarEventEntry();

myEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("Read the attachment"));
myEntry.setContent(yourContent);

//etc...
DateTime startTime = DateTime.parseDateTime("2006-04-17T15:00:00-08:00");
DateTime endTime = DateTime.parseDateTime("2006-04-17T17:00:00-08:00");
When eventTimes = new When();
eventTimes.setStartTime(startTime);
eventTimes.setEndTime(endTime);
myEntry.addTime(eventTimes);
```

Comment: I don't really know. With their API, you only load a byte array, and assign it a content type, so it could be possible... But I haven't found more info about it, and I'm sure Google restricts some file types and sizes for this apps.

Comment: I tried this but was unable to get it show up as an attachment, instead it just showed up in the text field.

Comment: Try changing the Mimetype yourContent.setMimeType(ContentType.XXXXX); (trying the different ContentType enum values)

Comment: Still haven't had any luck.  If I set the content type it doesn't show up at all... is there any way of doing it without the API?